# An unpleasant puzzle

Tags: knowledge, visual

Based on the image below, can you determine who I am?

---

[image]

---

**Who Am I?**

Comment: You are @Prim3numbah!

Comment: @Magma Oh, how hilarious you are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm tempted to try

> [image: Rena Lalgie] (Picture UK Government OGL)

who is

> [Rena Lalgie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rena_Lalgie) Governor of Bermuda (or alternatively King Charles III).

because

> The triangle is roughly oriented like (and coloured similarly to) the somewhat unpleasant Bermuda Triangle. One corner of which is in Florida (part of the US head of state by Joe Biden); one part of corner of which is in Puerto Rico (though Joao Mendonca identifies the other picture as Rodrigo Chaves the President of Costa Rica); and one corner of which is in Bermuda.

I'd be more confident of my answer if the pictures were of

> [Ron DeSantis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_DeSantis) and [Pedro Pierluisi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedro_Pierluisi).

Comment: Well done! I was actually unsure of which ppl to place, but chose to go for the presidents/premier of each country/region. The missing person intended was the premier of that region.

Comment: @Prim3numbah It seems you may have rot13(pbasyngrq Chregb Evpb naq Pbfgn Evpn)

Comment: @Cap Oh, I absolutely did. Surprised I didn't see that. Similar city names.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be Laurentino Cortizo?

Since the images depict the president of the USA and Costa Rica, my guess would be the president of Panama due to it´s proximity with Costa Rica and economical importance to both the USA and Costa Rica.